# Pandas create multiple dataframe based on group from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jhon','Andy','Jenny','Joan','Paul','Rosa'],
                 'Position':['Programmer','Designer','Programmer','Designer','Analyst','Analyst']})
```

I want to create multiple of other dataframe based on the Position, and named each dataframe as "Job_as_"

Expected output would be

```
Job_as_Programmer=['Jhon','Jeny']
Job_as_Designer=['Andy','Jhon']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary:

```
{"Job_as_"+ x : df.loc[df.Position==x, "Name"].to_list() for x in df.Position.unique()}
```

**Output**

```
{
 'Job_as_Programmer': ['Jhon', 'Jenny'],
 'Job_as_Designer': ['Andy', 'Joan'],
 'Job_as_Analyst': ['Paul', 'Rosa']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `pandas.Series.add_prefix`:

```
df2 = df.groupby("Position")["Name"].apply(list)
df2.add_prefix("Job_as_").to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'Job_as_Analyst': ['Paul', 'Rosa'],
 'Job_as_Designer': ['Andy', 'Joan'],
 'Job_as_Programmer': ['Jhon', 'Jenny']}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just use `groupby` as below:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jhon','Andy','Jenny','Joan','Paul','Rosa'],
                     'Position':['Programmer','Designer','Programmer','Designer','Analyst','Analyst']})
newDf = df.groupby(["Position" , "Name"]).first()
newDf #To Print Table
```

Output:

```
Position    Name
Analyst     Paul
            Rosa

Designer    Andy
            Joan

Programmer  Jenny
            Jhon
```